# Open website with subdirectory blocked by ip address?

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm trying to block a subdirectory on my website that is open to the public. Nothing I've tried has been successful. Is this section from my conf enough to determine what's wrong?

This is on Apache 2.4.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/website.example>
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/website.example/private>
  AllowOverride None
  <RequireAny>
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
    Require ip 5.6.7.8
  </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

Update: This issue has been solved. I stupidly forgot to include "httpdocs" in both of the `Directory` lines. After correcting that error the access by IP works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was a dumb mistake. I forgot "httpdocs" in the Directory paths. After that fix, access control worked as expected.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/website.example/httpdocs>
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/website.example/httpdocs/private>
  AllowOverride None
  <RequireAny>
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
    Require ip 5.6.7.8
  </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```